# Delete a Firebase Android app, then use its SHA1 and package name in another project

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-console

I'm using Firebase for its Firebase Cloud Messaging service. I have 2 account, each of which has a project with and Android App.

```
Account A -> Project A -> Android App A
Account B -> Project B -> Android App B
```

I need to delete Project A and migrate everything to Project B (Android and iOS apps, nothing else).

Here's what I've done so far:

1. deleted Android App A
2. created Project B
3. created Android App B

I now need to add the SHA1s, used in Android App A, in Android App B, but I always get an error.

I'm thinking this could need some time to take effect, during which time I can't use the same SHA1 in another app.

- Is this the case?
- How long should it take?
- Am I missing something?

Comment: Any reason you need to reuse the SHA1? It takes up to 30 days to completely purge an app. I don't know if the SHA1 becomes reusable after that time.

Comment: Yep, the app is already published on the Google Play Store, but we need to move the project from one account to another. I solved the problem by deleting the whole project.

Comment: Hi @DavidCorsalini, how long did deleting take? I am having same problem and accidentally set production sha1 into test project. I deleted that project also but seems like it will take another few days to take effect. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It takes up to 1 month to delete a project from firebase to prevent unintended removal. AFAIK, you cannot use your key during that period.

upd. If you used a debug store (usually placed in `~/.android/debug.keystore`) and generated 'androiddebugkey' like this

```
keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey \
-keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore \
-storepass android -keypass android
```

you can always delete the `~/.android/debug.keystore` file and generate new SHA1.